# Scala Intellij running test suite

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, build, sbt

I am doing the Scala course on coursera. I am trying to run the unit tests given in the exercise. However, I am getting the following issues:

```
Error:(3, 12) object scalatest is not a member of package org
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
           ^

Error:(6, 12) object junit is not a member of package org
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
           ^
```

These appear when I am importing packages into my project:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
```

I googled this and found the following solution:
Add dependencies like this

```
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % "test->default"
```

I tried adding this code to `build.sbt` but the errors persist.

Comment: Have you restarted sbt? Have idea re-import project (load new dependency)? Have new dependency appears in the list of external libraries of project structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScalaTest is not JUnit. Adding the `junit-interface` is needed if you want to execute JUnit tests directly with sbt. Obviously you are trying to run ScalaTest tests, though. The additional library dependency you need here is

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % "test"
```

And then to include JUnit (instead of the junit-sbt-interface), probably this:

```
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
```